# Background Parallax Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

I am trying to create a website using the background effect exactly similar as implemented in this website,  http://brightmedia.pl/ . 
On inspect element the div that creating the parallax effect on background from mouse move and scroll as well, we can see that it is changing the translate3D() property of the element on mouse move. Please guide me how can I achieve this same background effect?

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through the following articles on how you can achieve a parallax effect. The first step is to create the parallax effect then you can achieve the line effect and modify it to your needs.

**How To Create A Parallax Scrolling Website:**
https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website

**Simple Parallax Scrolling is:** 
https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/

**How To Create a Parallax Scrolling Effect:** 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

**How TO - Scroll Drawing:**
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scrolldrawing.asp

**How SVG Line Animation Works:**
https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

```
Please find below 21 Impressive SVG Line Animation along with the code:
```

**21 Impressive SVG Line Animation Examples:**
http://bashooka.com/coding/impressive-svg-line-animation-examples/